# Error: unexpected '=' in: when using mutate()

Tags: r

I am trying to change the numeric value 93.2142 to -93.2142 and 93.18124 to -93.18124 in a column named "Camelot GPS Longitude". I keep getting errors for this code:

```
site <- site %>% 
    mutate("Camelot GPS Longitude" = recode("Camelot GPS Longitude", 
        93.2142 = -93.2142, 
        93.18124 = -93.18124))
```

I have looked on a number of websites, posts, tried altering my code a variety of ways, but I can't figure out why the "=" is an issue.

Comment: Variable names should be _symbols_, not strings, you can do `mutate(x = ...)` but not `mutate("x" = ...)`. In your case, to create a symbol with whitespace in it, you need to use tildes \`. Change "Camelot GPS Longitude" to \`Camelot GPS Longitude\`.

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro Actually, the issue is with the `=` in `recode`, not the column name in `mutate()`, but your description of the issue is correct, just in the wrong place.

Comment: In order to use `recode()` on numeric variables (although this function has been superseded) you need to use backticks to convert the values to labels. If you look at the examples under `?recode` you'll see an example for a numeric variable addressing this. But probably best to move away from `recode()`. In this case, it would be much better to just use `if_else` and multiply the values by -1.

Comment: My bad, you actually can do `mutate("x" = ...)`. I also meant backtick, not "tilde". Thanks @joran

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and do not rely on the equality of double values like this, even when replacing `recode` with `case_match` (consider `(0.0001 + 0.0002) == 0.0003` returning `FALSE`). There's a good chance that the dataset includes cardinal direction (i.e. `93.2142 W` ) or some other reliable means to figure out if longitudes are West or East of Greenwich .

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be those specific values? why not just multiply by -1?

site <- site %>%
mutate(`Camelot GPS Longitude` =  `Camelot GPS Longitude` * -1

Comment: No I just want to change those two specific values and leave the rest of the values in the column as they are.